# QTableWidget performance optimization

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget that can display a huge number of elements (like, 20000 elements). Displaying per se and scrolling up and down works find, however, populating the widget works extremely slowly. I found out that constructing the QVector of elements (strings) that are displayed works very fast, however, inserting the elements into the QTableWidget is very slow.
I need to implement filtration over the elements, so if the user filters half of the elements out with a wildcard, it's still necessary to clean the QTreeWidget and insert 10000 elements back (or hide 10000 elements which is equally slow). Reasonably fast performance is critical here because the user can't wait for several minutes every time he presses a button.
Valgrind doesn't help much as apparently much of the resources are eaten by some implicitly called functions, particularly `QHeaderView::sectionSize()` and `QHeaderView::isSectionHidden()`

Comment: Hi ! You always have to put heavy tasks in a separate thread to not freeze the GUI.

Comment: I performance is critical, consider using `QTableView` with a model instead.

Comment: 'QTreeWidget' in your question looks like misprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migrate Your code to model-view pattern.

1. Create a model (subclass `QStandardItemModel`) and place all Your data there.
2. Display all the data in `QTableView`, ensure everything is OK
3. Now, You can use  `QSortFilterModel` model for fast data-filtering, or you can subclass QProxyModel for more complex filters.